# Element-Plus Global API not working with Vue 3 Global API

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

I'm trying to use the ElementPlus as a [global API](https://element-plus.org/en-US/guide/installation.html#hello-world) but it is not working.
I add the Vue 3 unpkg link in HTML and ElementPlus unpkg link to run. But no output for ElementPlus.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <!-- import CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css">
    <!-- import JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>
    <title>Element Plus demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <el-button>{{ message }}</el-button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const App = {
        data() {
          return {
            message: "Hello Element Plus",
          };
        },
      };
      const app = Vue.createApp(App);
      app.use(ElementPlus);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser's dev tools.  The network tab shows 404 for the vue package, and it's obvious why when you try to open the link https://unpkg.com/vue@next

The Element Plus [documentation](https://element-plus.org/en-US/guide/installation.html#unpkg) for unpkg shows what the link should actually be: https://unpkg.com/vue@3

Your updated code should then be:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <!-- import CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css">
    <!-- import JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>
    <title>Element Plus demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <el-button>{{ message }}</el-button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const App = {
        data() {
          return {
            message: "Hello Element Plus",
          };
        },
      };
      const app = Vue.createApp(App);
      app.use(ElementPlus);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```